# db2: loading ebcdic data from mainframe into Linux to stay ebcdic

Tags: database, load, db2, ebcdic

I need to load tables coming from a mainframe DB2 (i.e with data encoded into EBCDIC) onto a Linux DB2 and keep them EBCDIC in Linux.

I tried to play with the TERRITORY and CODEPAGE parameters on the CREATE DATABASE on Linux but could not reach the right values.

Could somebody please tell me how to do that ? Thanks in advance

regards

didier

Comment: _Why_ do you want to keep the data as EBCDIC?  Given the number of other questions dealing with translating it, I'd have thought you'd want to _avoid_ it in the future... I'm not sure, because the documentation appears at little obtuse, but it looks like EBCIDC _may_ be used behind the scenes.  What actual machine are you on, not just OS?  Beyond that, you might try `IBM-37`, as `CCSID 037` is the 'standard' choice for SQL tables on our iSeries.

Comment: Does DB/2 for Linux support EDBDIC?  If not you may have to use BLOBs